# Using dataTable with Primefaces DynaForms

Tags: jsf, primefaces-extensions

I've been trying to use dataTable with dynaforms, with no success; I get no results. I've been able to generate results with dataList, though. Can someone please explain what I need to correct? I have used both p:dataTable and h:dataTable.  I surrounded the dataList reference with comments so you can see what I did.

```
<h:form id="frm">
   <p:panel >
      <h:panelGroup>
         <!--<p:dataList value="#{dynalogBean.cannedList}" var="allValues">-->
         <p:dataTable value="#{dynalogBean.cannedList}" var="allValues">
             <pe:dynaForm value="#{allValues}" var="data">
                 <pe:dynaFormControl>
                     <p:outputLabel value = "#{data}" />
                 </pe:dynaFormControl>

                 <pe:dynaFormControl type="CT" for="vals">
                     <h:outputText id="vals" value = "#{data.value}" />
                 </pe:dynaFormControl>
             </pe:dynaForm>  
          </p:dataTable>  
          <!--</p:dataList> -->
       </h:panelGroup>
   </p:panel >
</h:form >
```

Comment: Just check all the PF datatable showcase examples, check the documentation, check all tutorials /examples/code on the internet, including all on stackoverflow. in none of them the datatable has any other child than `p:column(s)`(and ajax and facet)

Comment: Per Oleg from the PrimeFaces dev team, it can be done. I have searched stackflow but saw no solutions.

Comment: Sure it can be done IF you put it INSIDE a `p:column` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `p:datatable` render time does not support any other tags as effective children than

- `f:facet`
- `p:ajax`
- `p:column`
- `p:columns`

Composites work as long as they contain one of these four tags.

So if you put your `pe:dynaForm` inside a `p:column` tag, it works.